Azure Function App Authentication not working
I'm trying to secure a Serverless NodeJS Function App as mentioned in this example:
https://docs.cloudera.com/dataflow/cloud/azure-functions/topics/cdf-azure-function-secure-app.html
I set the Configuration settings to:

HTTP 1.1
HTTPS Only - On
TLS - 1.2
Client certificate mode - Require
No exclusion rules

I set the Authentication settings to:

App Service authentication - Enabled
Restrict access - Require authentication
Unauthenticated requests - Return HTTP 403 Forbidden
Token store - Enabled
OpenId Metadata URL, Client ID + Secret

In code I set a different http code to identify which step generated id.
export async function httpTrigger(request: HttpRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {

        if (!request.user) {
            return {
                status: 406, // Not Acceptable
            };
        }

    const name = request.query.get('name') || await request.text() || 'world';

    return { body: `Hello, ${name}!` };
};

app.http('httpTrigger', {
    methods: ['POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: httpTrigger
});

With any Bearer token (valid or invalid) I'm getting HTTP 406 response (from function app). If I change to authLevel 'function' every request is 401 Unauthorized.
Is there something I'm missing ?

I followed the below steps in the Azure function app to authenticate using a certificate.
Code :
import { app, HttpRequest, HttpResponseInit, InvocationContext } from "@azure/functions";

export async function httpTrigger1(request: HttpRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
    context.log(Http function processed request for url "${request.url}");

    if(!request.user) {
        return {
            status: 406,
        }
    }
    
    const name = request.query.get('name') || await request.text() || 'world';
    return { body: Hello, ${name}! };
};

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: httpTrigger1
});

I added the identity provider as Azure AD app in the Azure function app Authentication as a Single page application as shown below,

I set the Client certificate mode as Require in the Azure function app Configuration as below,

I uploaded a .cer certificate in the Azure AD app as below,

I granted the admin consent permissions as shown below,

Output :
When I entered my Azure function app URL in the browser, I got the below page to select my certificate for authentication,
https://kamfunstr.azurewebsites.net/api/httptrigger1


I got the below output after the above authentication with the certificate.

https://kamfunstr.azurewebsites.net/api/httptrigger1?name=kamali


Note : Below is another option for certificate authentication in the Azure function app.
If you set the Unauthenticated requests as Return HTTP 302 as below,

Then, you will get an option to select a certificate, your account for sign in and you will get the output as below,



@Ricardo Henrique Comar Can you get a chance to look into the above solution I provided? Hope this works for you.
